# How to move to a view in an other html page with Dojo Mobile?

Tags: html, mobile, dojo, transition

I want to do this [Dojo transition to another html file in same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445033/dojo-transition-to-another-html-file-in-same-project/21426151#21426151). Select a view from an other html page, the code available on the link is very similar to what I have in my project. While the solution is accepted, I'm unable to have success with it whereas I have tested it several times. Can someone check it, please ?

Thank you in advance

Here are two html files that allow you testing it, it's not my real code but that provides same result :

**Index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<title>Index</title>
<!-- application stylesheet will go here -->
<!-- dynamically apply native visual theme according to the browser user agent -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.6/dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"></script>
<!-- dojo configuration options -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojoConfig = {
        async: true,
        parseOnLoad: false
    };
</script>
<!-- dojo bootstrap -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs /dojo/1.9.6/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<!-- dojo application code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
require(["dojox/mobile/parser",
"dojox/mobile/ViewController",                   
"dojox/mobile",              
"dojox/mobile/ScrollableView",
"dojox/mobile/TabBar",
"dojox/mobile/Switch",
"dojox/mobile/deviceTheme",
"dojox/mobile/compat",                   
"dojox/mobile/IconMenu",
"dojox/mobile/SimpleDialog",
"dojox/mobile/Button",
"dojox/mobile/Heading",
"dijit/registry",
"dojo/domReady!",
"dojo/dom",
"dojo/ready"
         ], function(parser) {
                parser.parse();
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="detailsHeading" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
    data-dojo-props="fixed: 'top', label: 'Details', back:'Back', moveTo:'view1', transition:'slide', transitionDir:'-1',url:'sample.html'">
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

**sample.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<title>Sample</title>
<!-- application stylesheet will go here -->
<!-- dynamically apply native visual theme according to the browser user agent -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.6/dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"></script>
<!-- dojo configuration options -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojoConfig = {
        async: true,
        parseOnLoad: false
    };
</script>
<!-- dojo bootstrap -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.6/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<!-- dojo application code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
require(["dojox/mobile/parser",
                 "dojox/mobile/ViewController",                  
                 "dojox/mobile",
                 "dojox/mobile/ScrollableView",
                 "dojox/mobile/TabBar",
                 "dojox/mobile/Switch",
                 "dojox/mobile/deviceTheme",
                 "dojox/mobile/compat",                  
                 "dojox/mobile/IconMenu",
                 "dojox/mobile/SimpleDialog",
                 "dojox/mobile/Button",
                 "dojox/mobile/Heading",
                 "dijit/registry",
                 "dojo/domReady!",
                 "dojo/dom",
                 "dojo/ready"
         ], function(parser) {
                parser.parse();
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="view1" data-dojo-props="selected:false,scrollDir:'v'">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Put them in a same directory and test it

Comment: what is the error? You need to provide more information. Provide your code in the question. where is the HTML fragment file placed, Is it accessible.?

Comment: My both html pages are in the same directory. The code is exactly the one in the link. Have you tested it ?

Comment: The link does not provide complete code. You need to show us what is your code. There can be failures at various points. We cannot make assumptions on what you have done. Show us your complete HTML file with the Head, Body tags or create a jsFiddle. Asking us to refer to some other link which does not provide us helpful information will not suffice.

Comment: There are so many errors in your code. That's the reason I asked to show me your code. Will need a lengthy answer. Hang on...will get back to you on this.

Comment: Okay thank you :D, that's not really my code though, I made a quick thing to show you that the solution of the link doesn't work but if you fix it I think I'll be able to fix the issue in my project

Answer (score 0):

The Main Html File.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

    <!-- dojo stylesheet will go here -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.6/dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"></script>

    <title>Dojo Mobile Simple View</title>

    <!-- dojo configuration options -->
    <script>
        dojoConfig = {
            async: true,
            parseOnLoad: false
        };
    </script>
    <!-- dojo bootstrap -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.6/dojo/dojo.js"></script>


    <script>
        require([
            "dojox/mobile/parser",
            "dojo/ready",
            "dojox/mobile/ScrollableView",
            "dojox/mobile/Heading",
            "dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton"
        ], function (parser, ready ) {

            ready ( function() {

                parser.parse();
            });

        });

    </script>


</head>
<body style="visibility:hidden;">

<!-- the view or "page"; select it as the "home" screen -->
<div id="view1" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ScrollableView" data-dojo-props="selected:true">
    <div id="detailsHeading" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading"
         data-dojo-props="fixed: 'top', label: 'View1'">

        <span id="rightbtn" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton"
            style="float:right;"
            data-dojo-props="transition:'slide', transitionDir:'-1',url:'Sample.html' ">Sample
        </span>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The **Sample.html** file is a HTML Fragment it should **NOT** contain head, body tags.

```
<!-- Sample View -->
<div id="sample" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ScrollableView" >
    <!-- heading -->
    <h1 id="edit1" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading"
        data-dojo-props=" fixed:'top' ">Sample
    </h1>

</div>
```